# Setup Sunspot-search with a has_many ... through-connection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, many-to-many, has-many-through, sunspot

I'm trying to implement a Sunspot-search: My model "Photo" has_many "Categories" :through "Tags". So the search should be able to look for a photo's name and with the possibility to search for only those, that are tagged with a certain category- with the params looking like such:
search?name=aaa&categories=bbb+ccc
...which, as an example, should give all photos with aaa in the name and that are tagged with bbb and/or ccc

The problem lies in the searchable block in the photo.rb-model. I can't figure out, how to set things up and there seems to be no help for has_many :through connections available.

Currently I'm stuck with

```
photo.rb:

searchable do
  text :name
  ...
  integer :tag_ids, :multiple => true, :references => Tag do |p|
    p.tags.map(&:id)
  end
  integer :category_ids, :multiple => true, :references => Category do
    categories.map(&:id)
  end
  text :categories do |p|
    p.categories.map(&:name)
  end
end

category.rb:
searchable do
  text :name
  integer :id
end
```

which gives me a

```
undefined method `categories' for #<Sunspot::DSL::Search:0x5d7d208>
```

How do the searchable blocks have to be altered? Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

ok, there was a mistake in my controller-syntax. has-many-through-relationships are just the same as has-many-relationships in sunspot.